# ContextMenu behaviour between parent and child controls

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu, tabcontrol

I have TabControl(tb1) with 2 pages. Within of the pages I have another TabControl with 1 page (tb2).

I have contectmenu assigned only to tb1. But when I right click on tb2, it also displays the same context menu which is assigned to parent (tb1).

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/contextmenustrip .. try this..

you need to assign context menu to both tabs i guess

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457677/tabcontrol-context-menu