# ContextMenuStrip not showing on devex XtraTabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, devexpress, contextmenu

I'm using c#/winforms with a devex xtratabcontrol. I need to be able to right click on a tab header and get a context menu to appear. I tried working based on the first answer in this link: [TabControl Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457677/tabcontrol-context-menu), but for some reason when I click, I see the event firing, but nothing appearing on the screen.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
ContextMenuStrip menuStrip=new ContextMenuStrip();
ContextMenu menu=new ContextMenu();
menu.MenuItems.Add("click me", new EventHandler(temp_click));
menuStrip.ContextMenu = menu;
mainTabControl.MouseClick += MainTabControl_MouseClick;


private void temp_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //nothing for now
}

private void MainTabControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
       this.menuStrip.Show(this.mainTabControl, e.Location);
    }
}
```

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding ToolStripMenuItems to your ContextMenuStrip:

```
ContextMenuStrip menuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
ToolStripMenuItem tsmi = new ToolStripMenuItem();
tsmi.Text = "click me";
tsmi.Click += temp_click;
menuStrip.Items.Add(tsmi);
```